# In iOS, why am I getting an SSL error when trying to download files from S3 over HTTPS?

Tags: ios, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm writing an iOS client for an existing Rails app.  I have some assets on Amazon S3 that this iOS client will need to download.  Download authorization is managed by the Rails backend and the [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) gem provides temporary signed URLs.  To keep the iOS client as simple as possible, I get signed URLs from the server instead of using the iOS AWS SDK.

For S3 files I want to download, I get a URL that looks something like

`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<my_bucket>/<my_filename>?AWSAccessKeyId=<access_key>&Expires=<expiration>&Signature=<signature>`.

When I try to download these URLs using `Alamofire.download`, I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x7f8b31474ce0>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=<CFArray 0x7f8b3382f950 [0x1059d47b0]>{type = immutable, count = 3, values = (
    0 : <cert(0x7f8b31496a90) s: *.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com i: VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3>
    1 : <cert(0x7f8b31496ce0) s: VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3 i: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5>
    2 : <cert(0x7f8b31496f30) s: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5 i: Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority>
)}
```

If I set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true in `Info.plist`, the download succeeds.

What aspect of the certificate is making this fail?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492693/why-is-my-servers-wildcard-ssl-certificate-being-rejected) suggests the wildcard certificate could be a problem.  However, my URLs work in mobile Safari and the wildcard is in the SAN section.  Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot the problem and make sure I can use SSL?

I'm using XCode 7.0.1, Swift 2.0 and targeting iOS 8.0.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that I DO want to use HTTPS and am hoping for advice on figuring out what is causing the Amazon-issued certificate to fail and how I can address that. The question this was marked as a duplicate of only seems to address using HTTP during testing.

Comment: You should look into [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-706/). Amazon S3's SSL certificate is currently not signed with SHA256 (it uses SHA1), and it is causing the ATS error on iOS 9 and later. Safari is not subject to ATS.

Comment: @YosukeMatsuda - you are awesome, it was indeed the SHA1 signature that caused the problem.  That hint led me to [this link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13472#41025) which states that setting `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` for `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` to true is the best solution.  I still can't find a written Apple document that states SHA-1 is not compatible with ATS, though.

Comment: @matt - with the extra context, I see that my question is a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500655/ios-9-app-download-from-amazon-s3-ssl-error-tls-1-2-support).